# Apple M1 java 8 extremely slow SSL connection

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, sbt, apple-m1

Just got top of the top Apple M1 Max laptop.

All of a sudden realised that it is not that fast when it comes to establishing ssl connection in Java 8.

As a matter of fact it is dead slow.

i have Play 2.3 project with lots of dependencies, but i have never succeed to run it coz downloading dependencies takes ages.

Same code on MacBook Pro 2020 runs fast (if it is applicable to sbt at all)

Thread dump reveals one thread in Net I/O state and periodically emerging (when something changes on the screen) HandShakeCompletedNotify-Thread

Moving away from antique Play 2.3 and java 8 is not an option.

More details: GlobalProtect VPN is enabled.

Does anybody have any idea what is going on?